# C - Casting ~0 to unsigned long

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion

I’ve seen low-level bitwise expressions that use `~0` to generate a bit-pattern of all `1`s, which is then used as masks, etc. For example on K&R page 45:

```
/* getbits: get n bits from position p */
unsigned getbits(unsigned x, int p, int n)
{
    return (x >> (p+1-n)) & ~(~0 << n);
}
```

In my machine, `(unsigned long) ~0` evaluates to `0x FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF`. This lets us easily generate `1` masks larger than `int`s and is kinda nice.

However, shouldn’t `(unsigned long) ~0` instead evaluate to `0x 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF`? Without any suffixes, `0` is considered an integer constant, so `~0` evaluates to `0x FF FF FF FF`. Why doesn’t casting this to `unsigned long` result in a zero-padded value? What am I missing here?

Edit: On my machine, `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long)` are 4 and 8, respectively.

Comment: `zero-padded value?` during integer promotion it pads with sign bit value (ie it is 1 padded for negative), otherwise `(long)-1` will not be equal to `-1L`

Comment: `~0` produces `(int)0xffffffff = -1` Casting to an unsigned type produces the unique unsigned value which is equal to the original value modulo 2^n where n is the number of unsigned bits. In your case, n=64, and the unique 64-bit value which is equal to `-1` modulo 2^64 is `0xffffffffffffffff`.

Comment: @Bob__ `sizeof(int) = 4` and `sizeof(long)=8`. I also added this to the post.

Comment: Hermit, To easily generate an `(unsigned long)` of all 1's use `ULONG_MAX` or perhaps `~0UL` or `-1UL`.  Avoid using _signed_ constants for this task.

Comment: @IłyaBursov This seems to be the case. I didn’t know C sign-extends the values even when they are being cased into larger unsigned types.

Comment: @Hermit This isn't actually sign-extension. The purpose of sign extension is to use more bits for storing a value but **keep** the original value. When you cast a negative value to an **unsigned** type the original value isn't kept.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica This works well for ints and longs. Is there also a clean way to generate `char`s and `short`s without casting a `~0u` to char?

Comment: Oh god this code is actually in K&R... For the love of undefined behavior put down that horrible book! You cannot left shift signed and negative numbers in C, this was widely known _before_ K&R 2nd edition was published. Just get rid of the book, it is actively harmful.

Comment: @Hermit For `char`, use `char all_ones = CHAR_MAX | CHAR_MIN;`.  Likewise for `short`.  Yet be advised: avoid _signed_ types for bit manipulation:  stay with `unsigned char`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned`, ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On your system `~0` is an `int` with bit pattern `FF FF FF FF` which represent the decimal value -1.

When you cast to `unsigned long` you convert one integer type to another integer. The rules for that can be found in 6.3.1.3 of the C (draft) standard n1570:

> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if
> the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.

> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
> subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
> until the value is in the range of the new type.<sup>60)</sup>

> <sub>*60) The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression.*</sub>

The first rule doesn't apply as -1 can't be represented in `unsigned long`. The second rule aplies, i.e. the new value is found like

```
new-value = original-value + (ULONG_MAX + 1)
```

In your case:

```
new-value = -1 + (ULONG_MAX + 1) = ULONG_MAX
```

so the new value is `ULONG_MAX` which has the representation `FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF` on your system.

Comment: To add a little detail: when doing these conversions, the equations should be carried out as pure abstract math without taking the widths of the operands in account. There is a helpful foot note at 6.3.1.3: "The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression." Maybe add that note to the answer for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the excellent response by @SupportUkraine, you should be aware that `return (x >> (p+1-n)) & ~(~0 << n);` invokes undefined behavior:

> **6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators**
>
> [...]
>
> 4 The result of **E1 << E2** is **E1** left-shifted **E2** bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If **E1** has an unsigned type, the value of the result is **E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>**, wrapped around. If **E1** has a signed type and nonnegative value, and **E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>** is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

`~0` has type `int` and a value of `-1`, hence `~0 << n` has undefined behavior for `n > 0`.  You should use `~0U << n` instead and use the type of `x` is larger than `unsigned int`. A generic expression for this is `~(0U * x) << n` for all unsigned types of `x`.