# How to understand memory layout and the meaning of address value in C on 64bits platform

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I run it on M1 macbook air with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202).

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 'A';
    unsigned int i = -1;
    unsigned int *ptr = &i;
    printf("%p\n",&ptr);
    printf("%p\n",ptr);
    printf("--------\n");
    char *p = (char *)ptr;
    printf("%p\n",&i);
    printf("%p\n",&a);
    printf("--------\n");
    printf("%p\n",p);
    printf("%p\n",p + 1);
    printf("%p\n",p + 2);
    printf("%p\n",p + 3);
    printf("%p\n",p + 4);
    printf("%p\n",p + 5);
    printf("%p\n",p + 6);
    printf("%p\n",p + 7);
    printf("--------\n");
    printf("%u\n",*p);
    printf("%u\n",*(p + 1));
    printf("%u\n",*(p + 2));
    printf("%u\n",*(p + 3));
    printf("%c %u\n",*(p + 4),*(p + 4));
    printf("%c %u\n",*(p + 5),*(p + 5));
    printf("%c %u\n",*(p + 6),*(p + 6));
    printf("%c %u\n",*(p + 7),*(p + 7));
}
```

I try to understand what is the memory layout in 64bits platform. Type int(unsigned int) has size of 4bytes, like the address says, the difference between address of variable `a` and `i` is 4. And the value of `i` is 2^32-1 which indicates it use exact 4bytes to present an int number. Type char has size of 1byte, so its pointer value adds 1 when adding 1 to it.

The strange thing to me is, each time the char pointer `p` increments, the value `p` pointing to is the same as `i` until `p` moves 'into' variable `a`. When in the line `p + 4`, its value equals to `'A'`.

In my understanding, 64bits means each memory location has 64bits to store, but type int only needs 32 bits, so each int variable is stored entirely within one memory location? But the pointer values and address values seems not support this. So does it means that each memory location has exact one byte?(I don't know where I can figure it out, so this may be a bad conjecture).

Second, why function `printf` prints 2^32-1 when the value of pointer `p` is 'inside' variable `i`, is this generally true or just a UB? But for `a = 'A'`, `printf` seems to perform differently, print `A 65` when `p + 4` and  `0` in the rest cases.

So what's the layout of a 64bits platform and how its memory works? And what's the meaning of the address value in C?

Or is there any books, manuals or documentations where I can find some explanations about this?

---

Update: I forget to add my own output

```
0x16da0b4f0
0x16da0b4f8
--------
0x16da0b4f8
0x16da0b4fc
--------
0x16da0b4f8
0x16da0b4f9
0x16da0b4fa
0x16da0b4fb
0x16da0b4fc
0x16da0b4fd
0x16da0b4fe
0x16da0b4ff
--------
4294967295
4294967295
4294967295
4294967295
A 65
 0
 0
 0
```

Comment: The number of bits in a 'memory location' depends on the type stored there.  If you store a pointer or an 8-byte integer, then a range of 8 bytes (64 bits) is used; if you store a single byte, then it occupies 1 byte.  So "64bits means each memory location has 64bits to store" is wrong (or, at best, over-simplistic).  The designation "64-bit machine" primarily refers to the width of the address bus — in theory, the machine can have as much as 2^64 bytes of memory accessed by address.  32-bit integers are stored in 32 bits (4 bytes).  Alignment requirements affect the layout too.

Comment: Quote: "In my understanding, 64bits means each memory location has 64bits to store" No, that's incorrect. The 64bit part rather refers to the size of the CPUs internal registers and thereby also to the maximum size of a pointer and thereby the addressable memory space (but systems doesn't use all 64 bits...). Anyway, most CPUs has 8 bit as the smallest memory location regardless of being 32 bit or 64 bit system. Exactly how the memory is accessed is another story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't in general learn about "memory layout in 64bits platform" by writing code and running it on a (single) system. You may learn stuff about the specific system but in general the C standard doesn't specify how the variables in your code is to be placed in memory. A lot of that is left for the implementation. In other words different (64 bit) systems, different compilers, different compiler options, etc. may change things. So careful with conclusions...

For this question:

> The strange thing to me is, each time the char pointer p increments, the value p pointing to is the same as i until p moves 'into' variable a. When in the line p + 4, its value equals to 'A'.

Assuming:

1. Your system uses 4 bytes `int`
2. Your system uses 2's complement encoding for signed integers
3. Your system uses **signed** `char`type

The first two above will mean that `i` is located in memory as `FF FF FF FF` for the integer value -1

When you set a `char` pointer `p` to point to `i` it will point to memory holding **the first** `FF` and it **will only access that single** `FF` when dereferencing the pointer. Due to number 3 above that value is also the integer value -1.

Then you print that value as an `unsigned int` using `%u`. That involves conversion from one integer type to another integer type. The C standard describes how that is done. For details see [C - Casting ~0 to unsigned long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75692524/c-casting-0-to-unsigned-long/75692688#75692688)

When you print the next char, i.e. `*(p + 1)` you read the second `FF` (and only the second) which is also -1 (due to point 3) and the same happens again.

And the same for `*(p + 2)` and `*(p + 3)`.

For fun you can try this code

```
unsigned int i = -1;

char *p = (char *)&i;
printf("Using char-pointer: %u\n",*p);
printf("Using char-pointer: %u\n",*(p + 1));
printf("Using char-pointer: %u\n",*(p + 2));
printf("Using char-pointer: %u\n",*(p + 3));

unsigned char *pu = (unsigned char *)&i;
printf("Using unsigned char-pointer: %u\n",*pu);
printf("Using unsigned char-pointer: %u\n",*(pu + 1));
printf("Using unsigned char-pointer: %u\n",*(pu + 2));
printf("Using unsigned char-pointer: %u\n",*(pu + 3));
```

to see the difference between signed and unsigned char types.

Output:

```
Using char-pointer: 4294967295
Using char-pointer: 4294967295
Using char-pointer: 4294967295
Using char-pointer: 4294967295
Using unsigned char-pointer: 255
Using unsigned char-pointer: 255
Using unsigned char-pointer: 255
Using unsigned char-pointer: 255
```

For the values accessed by reading bytes from your variable `a` it's the same that goes on:

```
unsigned int a = 'A'; ---> memory: 41 00 00 00 (assuming little endian)
```

so first time you read `41` (or `'A'`) and for the rest you read `00`

Comment: I ran your code, and it's the same output. So char pointers do read only one byte information, the 'strange' output comes from the implicit type conversion.

Comment: So, like the program shows, addresses like `0x16da0b4f8`, `0x16da0b4f9` and so on, each of them does store one byte information, but CPU would read its subsequent memories depending on its type, for example, if it's an int value, CPU reads from `0x...f8` to `0x...fb` which is 4bytes(32bits), if it's an pointer, CPU reads from `0x...f8` to `0x...ff` which is 8bytes(64bits)?

Comment: @tionway From your comments it seems you understand it correct.